# weird characters in my generated PDF

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, string

I'm getting  characters in my PDF, i've stripped out \r\n \r \n \t, trimmed everything, decoded html entities and stripped tags. Nothing helps. The data is coming from a MySQL database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the data look like when in MySQL?

Comment: What is the encoding is used in the MySQL database, how are you accessing the data, and how are you creating the PDF?

Comment: MySQL data has a bunch of tabs and spaces, i expected those tabs and spaces

Comment: @Matthew - mysql utf-8 encoding, access using php mysql_query, pdf being generated using fpdf library (fpdf.org)

Comment: @gAMB don't bump your question after just 20 minutes of inactivity. You could say that this time is pretty dead anyway(relatively). If after 12 hours or a day you still don't have any answers then try actually revising your question to include other things you've tried and more specifications for what you are using

Comment: Hmm... new question, how do you bump questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check string encoding (with mb_detect_encoding) before adding to pdf, is it unicode string? Data in MySQL db can be in unicode but your db connection can use some another encoding.

Comment: Interesting. The MySQL db is utf-8. How can I change the encoding of my db connection if that is the case?

Comment: To set connection encoding you should execute next query 
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'") 
right after mysql_connect. If your db collation isn't utf8_general_ci - set needed collation. If you have access to my.cnf you can add this query to it:
init-connect="SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'". More info there: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-connection.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using utf8_decode()?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

You might be using a font that is not available.

Comment: The text is displayed like Hello  There

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to determine its numeric value and replace it:

```
$str = 'Hello  World';
echo str_replace(chr(ord('')), '[removed]', $str);
```

**Output:**

```
Hello [removed] World
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$string = "testContainingSpecialCharsäöüöüäüß";
$pdf->Cell(0,0,$string);
```

What characters should have been displayed instead of those  things?

Answer (score 0):

FPDF doesn't support unicode characters, so that might be the cause of your problem. There's an extension you could try at http://acko.net/node/56, or alternatively you could switch to another PDF generator library (I recommend [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)).

Or you could try using iconv to convert the text from UTF-8 to a supported character set (ie. `$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $str);`) if you want to stick with FPDF.

Comment: We're using a FPDF extension actually, UFPDF which supports unicode

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the result of what happens when you copy / paste text from Microsoft word. Does the PDF file contain text from a MS Word document by any chance? That might be your problem. There are some interesting comments for converting and stripping these characters in PHP on the PHP.net website: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php#39383

I am only presuming it is MS Word characters in your PDF file.

Comment: No, it's crawled data from webpages, and the data where the characters show is only filled with tabs and spaces.